# Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio - Line break returned in computed columns

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a table in my SQL database with the following columns :
[first_name], [last_name], [full_name], [email_address], [title], [department]

The columns [full_name] is a computed columns with the following formula:
`([first_name]+' '+[last_name])`

It works well but the returned value contains a line break... which I don't want...

Here is an example:

```
[first_name]
Enzo
[last_name]
Pezzoni
```

[image]

How can I avoid having the line break when the value is returned by the computed column?

I tried using the function CONCATENATE, I tried removing the `+' '+`
But I can't solve this issue.

Comment: Your first or last names must already include the line-break. Check the data with `datalength()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to strip out the line breaks that must already exist:

```
select Replace(Concat(first_name, ' ', last_name),Char(13),'')
```

You might need to try `char(10)`, or even both eg `char(10) + char(13)`

Comment: The line break did already exist yes, sorry I thought I had deleted my question. Thank you very much for your help !